# Fullcalendar - Showing partial dates (for a night shift)

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm trying to show a calendar for a person that works a night shift. I intend to show a calendar type 'resourceTimeline' from the current day at 6 pm to the next day at 3 am.
I've tried

```
visibleRange: {
    start: '2021-04-13 18:00:00',
    end: '2020-04-14 03:59:59'
}
```

but it only shows the current date until midnight.
I tried using `slotMinTime` and `slotMaxTime` but if the slotMinTime is greater then slotMaxTime it crashes.

Here is my view definition:

```
nightShift: {
    type: 'resourceTimeline',
    slotDuration: { hours: 1 },
    visibleRange: {
        start: '2021-04-13T18:00:00',
        end: '2020-04-15 03:59:59'
    },
    buttonText: 'Night Shift',
    slotLabelFormat: [
        {
            day: 'numeric',
            weekday: 'short'
        },
        {
            hour: 'numeric',
            minute: 'numeric',
            hourCycle: 'h23'
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Comment: To me this looks like a bug, but you can check with the fullcalendar people. https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs

Answer (score 0):

You can set slotMaxTime to "28:00:00"